# Why did Ron tell Harry not to tell Hermione that Snatchers are ‘a bit dim’?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1* (2010), Ron gives Harry a wand and explains:

> Took it off a Snatcher a couple of weeks ago. **Don't tell Hermione this**, but they're a bit dim, Snatchers.

Why did Ron tell Harry not to tell Hermione this?

Comment: dare I ask, just what is a "snatcher"?

Comment: Think "Deatheater Light". Deatheaters are the HP equivalent with the 1940s nazis, i.e the bad guys.

Comment: @user2813274 They go around and kidnap people for the bad guys

Comment: *Snatcher*, not the *Snitch* from Quidditch.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

### Ron wants to impress Hermione.

Consequently, a fact that makes his achievement look easier and lessens the apparent danger he was in, is not something he wants Hermione to know.

Answer (score 30):

Ron wants to impress Hermione with his story of defeating snatchers.  He hopes it will make him look tough, impress Hermione, and she will forgive him for walking out.

But actually snatchers are "a bit dim" and so easy to beat.  Ron doesn't want Hermione to know that.